# How to Automatically Remove Default Video Links in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, media, permalinks

I am looking for the user to redirect to the home page when the user tries to access the video permalink.

```
function wpb_imagelink_setup() {
$image_set = get_option( 'image_default_link_type' );

if ($image_set !== 'none') {
    update_option('image_default_link_type', 'none');
}
}
add_action('admin_init', 'wpb_imagelink_setup', 10);
```

I tried the above code, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to redirect the users via template_redirect hook that you can use as per below.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

$image_set = get_option( 'image_default_link_type' );

if ( is_page($image_set) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.yourhomepage.com/', 301 ); 
  exit;
    }
}
```

Check the `$image_set` is getting correct URL.